# Microsoft Ad Authentication on iOS With Flutter: Failed with Authetnication Error

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am unable to connect to Microsoft's MSAL through Flutter. I have tried using Microsoft's sample application with Swift to connect to MSAL, and it worked perfectly. I believe that I have replicated the example project completely to make it work for Flutter, but I am getting an authentication error. Microsoft's sample iOS application [can be found here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc). This is my configuration for Flutter:

Info.plist:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>msauth.[MY BUNDLE ID]</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>msauth</string>
        <string>msauthv2</string>
        <string>msauthv3</string>
    </array>
```

In the podfile, I did not change anything except specifying iOS version '14.0' (to use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/azure_ad_authentication).

Here is the result when running `pod install`
[image]

com.microsoft.adalcache is also added to keychain sharing
[image]

Here is the Flutter app code (only one file, main.dart)

```dart
import 'package:azure_ad_authentication/azure_ad_authentication.dart';
import 'package:azure_ad_authentication/exeption.dart';
import 'package:azure_ad_authentication/model/user_ad.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Task Kitchen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Auth Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String info = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Info:',
            ),
            Text(
              info,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          (() async {
            AzureAdAuthentication pca = await AzureAdAuthentication.createPublicClientApplication(
              clientId: "[CLIENT_ID]",
              authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
              redirectUri: "msauth.[MY BUNDLE ID]://auth"
            );
            print(pca);

            try {
              UserAdModel? res = await pca.acquireTokenSilent(scopes: [
                "openid",
                "Calendars.Read",
                "Calendars.ReadBasic",
                "Tasks.ReadWrite"
              ]);
              print("Got access token silently: ${res?.accessToken}");
              setState(() {
                info = "Got it silently";
              });
            } catch (_) {
              try {
                UserAdModel? res = await pca.acquireToken(scopes: [
                  "openid",
                  "Calendars.Read",
                  "Calendars.ReadBasic",
                  "Tasks.ReadWrite"
                ]);
                print("Got access token after login: ${res?.accessToken}");
                setState(() {
                  info = "Got it after login";
                });
              } on MsalException catch (e) {
                setState(() {
                  info = "Failed with error ${e.errorMessage}";
                });
                rethrow;
              } catch (e) {
                setState(() {
                  info = "Other Error";
                });
                rethrow;
              }
            }
          })();
        },
        tooltip: 'Test',
        child: const Icon(Icons.login),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have double-checked everything and can confirm that I did not copy incorrectly any of the BUNDLE ID or Client ID variables.

Here is a screenshot of the app:

[image]

Console Log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            6.6s
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55465/aFmCmRyi5Ss=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 15 Pro...
flutter: Instance of 'AzureAdAuthentication'
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'MsalException'
#0      AzureAdAuthentication.acquireToken (package:azure_ad_authentication/azure_ad_authentication.dart:51:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:taskkitchen_test/main.dart:82:36)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What did I miss?

Edit: An easy work-around solution is to switch to using the aad_oauth package from flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth

Comment: Rather than simply showing the error message, show the whole exception object. There is likely to be more information that indicates what specifically went wrong.  Perhaps set a breakpoint so that you can examine the exception object in the debugger

Comment: The Exception Object only has 1 property: e.errorMessage and it is displayed on the Phone Screen Emulator: Failed with error: Authentication Error. No further information was provided.

Comment: [`MsalException`](https://pub.dev/documentation/msal_flutter/latest/msal_flutter/MsalException-class.html) appears to have a number of implementers. I think it would definitely be worthwhile examining your exception in the debugger. Right now all you know is "something went wrong". You need to gather more information.